# Ampersand at end of string not visible in browser

Tags: php, echo

I am print an string as below

Code:

```
echo "&words=".$rs['pw']."&";
```

Output:

> &words=Help|Good

Notice that the last `&` is not printed.

But when I add a space character after `&` then it gets printed as below

Code:

```
echo "&words=".$rs['pw']."& ";
```

Output:

> &words=Help|Good&

Now `&` is printed.

Why its happening and whats the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Works fine for me. Doesn't seem to see if there's a problem.

Comment: I can't think of what would be causing it right away, but does it still not print if you use single quotes instead of double quotes for the ampersand?

Comment: unable to reproduce the bug. closed.

Comment: @pssdbt: its not working with single quotes as well. Dont know why this is happening??

Comment: @thephpdeveloper: I have checked it on 2-3 machines, but its giving the same error, even I tried it on my web space which is provided by Godaddy, there still its creating the same problem. :)

Comment: does the script terminate early?

Comment: Or do you use `substr()` somewhere?

Comment: If you replace the space with some other random character, get's it stripped away also?

Comment: Or, if you `htmlspecialchars()` the test string before echoing, does the `&` still disappear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're outputting it to a web browser you should be escaping the & by using `&amp;` "&" in HTML is used a lot to escape strings, and in URL's so is a special char, like <> etc.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me

```
$rs['pw'] = "Help|Good";
echo "&words=".$rs['pw']."&";
```

Output

> &words=Help|Good&

Which leads me to a question: What is the context? Where is this code output, are you running it on a webserver and viewing in a browser? Is there no other code involved that can be causing this?

If the context is something like outputting in HTML then you need to make sure that it is in the right place. In HTML ampersand is special and you should escape it. Usually that means translating into `&amp;`

- [htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)
- [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: Yes, I am running it on web server and viewing it in browser and no other code included there, I just seen this so I have removed all the code and then tested it, still the same issue.

Comment: Ok i tested it on my webserver and it still works. Have you tested the exact code that i've given or do you have _any_ other code at all in your file? Like reading from database or anything?

Answer (score 1):

If you're outputting it in a web page, then the browser will interpret `&` special. Select at "view source" in your browser, and you will see the raw output. If you need it to appear in a html context, you will have to pass the string through `htmlspecialchars` before printing it. So:

```
$rs['pw'] = "Help|Good";
echo htmlspecialchars("&words=".$rs['pw']."&");
```